# R - Identify and remove duplicate rows based on two columns

Tags: r, duplicates, subset, unique

I have some data that looks like this:

```
Course_ID   Text_ID
33          17
33          17
58          17
5           22
8           22
42          25
42          25
17          26
17          26
35          39
51          39
```

Not having a background in programming, I'm finding it tricky to articulate my question, but here goes: I only want to keep rows where `Course_ID` varies but where `Text_ID` is the same. So for example, the final data would look something like this:

```
Course_ID   Text_ID
5           22
8           22
35          39
51          39
```

As you can see, `Text_ID` 22 and 39 are the only ones that have different `Course_ID` values. I suspect subsetting the data would be the way to go, but as I said, I'm quite a novice at this kind of thing and would really appreciate any advice on how to approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select those groups where there is no repeats of `Course_ID`.

In `dplyr` you can write this as -

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Text_ID) %>% filter(n_distinct(Course_ID) == n()) %>% ungroup

#  Course_ID Text_ID
#      <int>   <int>
#1         5      22
#2         8      22
#3        35      39
#4        51      39
```

and in `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[uniqueN(Course_ID) == .N], Text_ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ave` testing if not `anyDuplicated`.

```
x[ave(x$Course_ID, x$Text_ID, FUN=anyDuplicated)==0,]
#   Course_ID Text_ID
#4          5      22
#5          8      22
#10        35      39
#11        51      39
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Course_ID   Text_ID
33          17
33          17
58          17
5           22
8           22
42          25
42          25
17          26
17          26
35          39
51          39")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach with `rlist` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

your_data %>%
  split(~ Text_ID) %>%
  rlist::list.filter(length(unique(Course_ID)) == length(Course_ID)) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Course_ID Text_ID
      <dbl>   <dbl>
1         5      22
2         8      22
3        35      39
4        51      39
```

```
# Data used:
your_data <- structure(list(Course_ID = c(33, 33, 58, 5, 8, 42, 42, 17, 17, 35, 51), Text_ID = c(17, 17, 17, 22, 22, 25, 25, 26, 26, 39, 39)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm sure this approach works but I ended up using one of the other suggestions.