# R - Count combinations of values across rows (to make a chord diagram)

Tags: r, duplicates, unique, chord-diagram

This follows on from a question I just posted here (providing link for context): [R - Identify and remove duplicate rows based on two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68180226/r-identify-and-remove-duplicate-rows-based-on-two-columns)

The next thing I need to do is count combinations of values based on the `Text_ID` column. Here's a sample of what my data looks like:

```
Text_ID  Course_Code
39       MA3020
39       MA3120
59       MA3006
59       MA5902
89       MA2105
89       MA3006
89       MA5902
92       MA3023
92       MA3024
94       MA2023
94       MA3023
94       MA3024
97       MA3023
97       MA3024
```

To be clear, what I'm trying to ascertain is how many times two `Course_Code` share the same `Text_ID`. I imagine there are a few ways to approach this and/or present the data, but here's how it might look (FYI - I'm trying to get this data into a structure that will allow me to create a chord diagram, showing relationships between `Course_Code`):

```
From     To      Value
MA3020   MA3120  1
MA3006   MA5092  2
MA2105   MA3006  1
MA3023   MA3024  3
MA2023   MA3023  1
```

As you can see, MA3023 and MA3024 have the most `Text_ID` in common (3).

It gets a bit complicated (I think) because more than two course codes can share a `Text_ID`. E.g. `Text_ID` 89 and 94 all appear on three or more different `Course_Code`

Hopefully that's all clear. If not, happy to elaborate. Ultimately, my goal is to get my data into a format/structure that will allow me to visualise relationships between `Course_Code` using `Text_ID` as the shared value. If there's another way to approach this, feel free to suggest it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use

```
subset(as.data.frame.table(crossprod(table(df1))), Freq != 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, this can be solved using a *non-equi self join*:

```
library(data.table)
dt[, Course_Code := factor(Course_Code)]
dt[dt, on = c("Text_ID", "Course_Code < Course_Code"), 
   .(Text_ID, From = x.Course_Code, To = i.Course_Code), nomatch = NULL][
     , .N, by = .(From, To)]
```

> ```
>      From     To N
> 1: MA3020 MA3120 1
> 2: MA3006 MA5902 2
> 3: MA2105 MA3006 1
> 4: MA2105 MA5902 1
> 5: MA3023 MA3024 3
> 6: MA2023 MA3023 1
> 7: MA2023 MA3024 1
> ```

Apparently, this reproduces OP'S expected answer.

The difference to [akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68182769/3817004) is that it avoids duplicate counts as well as self-references, i.e., where `From` and `To` are equal.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("Text_ID  Course_Code
39       MA3020
39       MA3120
59       MA3006
59       MA5902
89       MA2105
89       MA3006
89       MA5902
92       MA3023
92       MA3024
94       MA2023
94       MA3023
94       MA3024
97       MA3023
97       MA3024")
```